# jQuery .hide() and .slideUp() and .slideDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to slide down and slide up a div.At the time of loading the div will be kept disappeared/hide.

In this regard I used `.hide()` to keep the div disappeared/hide at the time of loading and after that I used `.slideDown()` to slide down and `.slideUp()` slide up the div.

My problem is when the page loads that div appeared for a moment like 1 millisecond after that it disappears. But I would like to keep the div disappeared/hide at the time of loading.

How can I solve the problem ??

Comment: Apply CSS property `display: none;` to your `div` so it's hidden at loading then.

Comment: Where is your code? edit your post and add your code too.

Comment: https://i.imgflip.com/okhfq.jpg

Comment: You can use on load of windows

Comment: Since your JavaScript, and in your case I bet JQuery file, is loading after all DOM element have been loaded to perform some procedure like hidding, etc... You div is showed for a while, this is the time needed by the server to load all your HTML components. That was for the explaination part, refer to @D4V1D for the solution of course.

Comment: @abu abu Do what @D4V1D said, simple add the style display none like so `<p style="display:none;">Text</p>`

Answer (score 1):

You want to hide a specific `div` at page load. You don't need any `jQuery`/`JS` to do so.

Therefore, [as per my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583525/jquery-hide-and-slideup-and-slidedown?noredirect=1#comment51119617_31583525), use CSS only:

```
div {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css method to do this. At the time of load, add a class called "hidden" then, after the page fully loaded, remove that class and use fade in/fade out.

something like this:

```
$(documnet).ready(function() {
$("#element").addClass("hidden");
$("#element").fadeIn(); 
$("element").fadeOut();
});
```

Use the addClass property, to add a class to hide your div, then fade it back into view.

Answer (score 0):

First add display:none; in your CSS file.

```
div {
    display:none;
}
```

And add this script

```
$('div').slideDown().delay(300).slideUp();
```

If your are getting the same problem again, then it means your CSS file is taking more time to load, in this case you can add in-line style.

```
<div style="display:none"></div>
```